# Webpack devServer not proxying requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server

The issue is that webpack-dev-server simply is not proxying requests to my API.

My setup is that I have 1 repo with webpack.config.js at the root of course, and a client directory with all my front end stuff, and then the other directories are related to my express server. The front end code was initially in its own, separate repo before I moved it into the same directory as the express server, and it was proxying fine then.

When I say "does not work" I mean: webpack-dev-server spins up the front end of the app on localhost:9000, and when I make a request to `/api/foo` it tries to request `localhost:9000/api/foo` instead of `localhost:3100/api/foo` and shows a 504 error in the browser console. So webpack-dev-server is working, it's just not doing any proxying at all. here's what I think is the relevant code:

// webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./client",
    output: {
        publicPath: '/',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[name].[ext]',
                            outputPath: 'fonts/',
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
        contentBase: './',
        overlay: true,
        port: 9000,
        compress: true,
        proxy: {
            '/api/**': {
                target: 'http://localhost:3100',
                secure: false,
                changeOrigin: true,
            },
        },
    },
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
            template: './client/index.html',
            filename: './index.html',
        }),
        new CompressionPlugin(),
    ],
};
```

Comment: A 504 response status indicates that it is actually proxying through to your API (or something). If it wasn't, you'd get a 404. Do you see any error logs from your API?

Comment: I think it's the `**` in your proxy config. It doesn't look like that in the documentation ~ https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy

Comment: Since you're not using HTTPS and it's unlikely you're using a named virtual host, try just `proxy: { '/api': 'http://localhost:3100' }`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've already tried /api, /api/**, just ** etc but no combination seems to work. I retried /api as you suggested anyway but no luck :/ I'm getting a 504 from webpack dev server I believe, not from my server (no logs, doesn't try to hit the correct URL). This is what I see in the browser console: `POST http://localhost:9000/api/auth/login 504 (Gateway Timeout)` where it should be trying to hit locahost 3100

Comment: You won't see the proxied address in the browser. As far as it knows, it's making a same-origin request; the proxying happens invisibly. Can you confirm that you can reach the API using `curl` or Postman?

Comment: Apparently Webpack returns a 504 response if it can't reach the proxied server. Definitely try with curl or Postman, eg `curl -v -X POST http://localhost:3100/api/auth/login`. Alternately, try enabling CORS on your API server (very easy with Express middleware) and make requests directly from JS

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help, I think I figured out the issue, i'll post it below and mark as resolved unless anyone else was doing the same silly mistake as me :)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who runs across the same issue, it appears to be a very silly mistake on my part that was due to my npm script. This was my script:

`webpack-dev-server --open --mode development && npm run server:dev`

So webpack-dev-server was running, but I don't think it ever got to the second part of this which is `npm run server:dev` - the thing that starts up my server. Thanks to Phil who commented on my question and suggested I try to hit the API with postman, which made me realise the server wasn't running and that made me realise the error.